# My custom MembershipProvider "does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.*"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to make a custom MembershipProvider, so I created a class called `CustomMemberhsipProvider`, and I made it inherit from `MembershipProvider`:

```
namespace Solution.Models
{
    public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public bool CheckPassword(string password, string SaltedHash)
        {
            //code
        }

        public string CreateHash(string saltAndPassword)
        {
            //code
        }

        public string GetUserRoles(string userName)
        {
            //more code etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Then I referenced it in my `web.config` file like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="Solution.Models.CustomMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

**PROBLEM:** I get a zillion run-time errors telling me that `CustomMembershipProvider does not implement inherited abstract member MembershipProvider.ApplicationName.get / MembershipProvider.ApplicationName.set / MembershipProvider.ChangePassword(string, string, string) etc.`

**QUESTION:** What exactly is going on here? Shouldn't `CustomMembershipProvider` inherit all of the properties and functions of `MembershipProvider` without any extra work?  Am I missing something simple?

I did some research on this, and I am assuming [by virtue of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1875961/3474146) that the issue is Visual Studio automatically filling in every property missing from `CustomMembershipProvider` with a `throw new NotImplementedException();`.  Nevertheless, that particular answer didn't help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure those are compile-time errors and not runtime errors that you are seeing.

`MembershipProvider` is an abstract class, and in order to create a concrete implementation of an abstract class, you must provide implementations for (at least) all of its abstract members. Your class only has three explicit members (none of which are implementing `MembershipProvider`'s abstract members), whereas by my count, the `MembershipProvider` has 27 abstract members, so you are at least 27 members short.

MSDN has an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.85).aspx) on how to implement custom membership providers, and it contains the text:

> > The following tables list the required properties and methods that you must implement from the ProviderBase and MembershipProvider abstract classes and a description of each. To review an implementation of each member, see the code supplied for the Sample Membership Provider Implementation.

followed by a very long table of properties and methods.

In addition to the above article, I also suggest reading up on [abstract classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf(v=vs.71).aspx) as well, because you don't seem to be quite clear on what inheriting an abstract class entails.

And here are some helpful articles that include information on setting up identity in ASP.NET using the built-in functionality (the TYPE CAST EXCEPTION blog has several different posts on ASP.NET identity).

[Deploy a Secure ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Membership, OAuth, and SQL Database to an Azure Website](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/)

[Customizing profile information in ASP.NET Identity in VS 2013 templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx)

[TYPE CAST EXCEPTION - ASP.NET MVC and Identity 2.0: Understanding the Basics](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I guess the solution is to implement all members of `MembershipProvider` in `CustomMembershipProvider` (I got thrown off by this tutorial: http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Membership-Provider-for-MVC, but it doesn't seem worth it if all I want to do is have `MembershipProvider` grab users from a database of my own.  I'll have to think of another way to get authentication working.

Comment: Unless you have an already existing database or a very compelling reason, I think it would be counter-productive to try to make your own database access layer for membership. I've posted some additional links to helpful information on ASP.NET identity.